# Pycharm: MySQLdb and database

Tags: mysql, database, python-2.7, pycharm

**the code in Pycharm :**

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("127.0.0.1", "xxx", "xxx", "xxxxxxx")

cursor = db.cursor()

sql="""CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
       FIRST_NAME  CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
       LAST_NAME  CHAR(20),
       AGE INI,
       SEX  CHAR(1),
       INCOME FLOAT )"""

cursor.execute(sql)

db.close()
```

**the problem :**

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/mfae/PycharmProjects/dbs/create.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py:1031: UserWarning: /home/mfae/.python-eggs is writable by group/others and vulnerable to attack when used with get_resource_filename. Consider a more secure location (set with .set_extraction_path or the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment variable).
  warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mfae/PycharmProjects/dbs/create.py", line 14, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql)
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INI,\n       SEX  CHAR(1),\n       INCOME FLOAT )' at line 4")

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Process finished with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1

**what the solution ?**

Comment: Change the datatype of `AGE` to `INT`.

Comment: AGE INI? or AGE INT?

Comment: thanks all the solution done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error says, you should 
change `AGE INI`  to `AGE INT`.